# Give alias to anonymous column of global collection type in SELECT FROM TABLE(collection)

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, user-defined-types, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to use values from an `apex_t_numbers` collection in a `SELECT` query as `WITH` subquery:

```
atn_cur_ids := apex_string.split_numbers(arg_v_ids, ':');
-- So if arg_v_ids := '1:2:3', then atn_cur_ids := apex_t_numbers(1, 2, 3)

with t_cur_ids as (
  select * as id from table(atn_cur_ids);
)
select text from t_texts 
join t_cur_ids on t_texts.id = t_cur_ids.id
```

And here's the problem - `apex_t_numbers` is a table of `number`, not of `record` type with named fields. Oracle SQL doesn't allow to give aliases to a `*` even if it has only one single "anonymous" column.

A possible solution could be a function that both

1. receives `*` and
2. returns value per row

But I am aware of only one that can get a `*` and return something - `count(*)`, and it doesn't meet the second requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, found a solution. It could be done with `column_value` as a name of column:

```
with t_cur_ids as (
  select column_value as id from table(atn_cur_ids);
)
select text from t_texts 
join t_cur_ids on t_texts.id = t_cur_ids.id
```